# How to extract concatenated string values in columns of a data.table in R, and expanding it length-wise with a counter column?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R that appears like

```
    V=data.table(person=c(1,1,2,3),task=c("A","A","B","C"),scores=c("Low|Low|High|Medium","Low","High|Low",""))
    > V
      person task              scores
    1:     1    A Low|Low|High|Medium
    2:     1    A                 Low
    3:     2    B            High|Low
    4:     3    C
```

I would like to extract all the elements between the `|`, expanding length-wise, and then adding a counter by `person` and `task`. By doing

```
> V[, list(score = unlist(strsplit(scores, "\\|"))), by = .(rater, task)]
   rater task  score
1:     1    A    Low
2:     1    A    Low
3:     1    A   High
4:     1    A Medium
5:     1    A    Low
6:     2    B   High
7:     2    B    Low
```

I can get the expansion, but I am unable to add a `counter` column which would show

```
       rater task  score  counter
    1:     1    A    Low     0
    2:     1    A    Low     1
    3:     1    A   High     2
    4:     1    A Medium     3
    5:     1    A    Low     4
    6:     2    B   High     0
    7:     2    B    Low     1
```

Each attempt I have is futile when there are missing scores.

Comment: What do you mean by "when there are missing scores."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can sequence along `.N` within each group using `rowid`:

```r
V[, list(score = unlist(strsplit(scores, "\\|"))), by = .(person, task)
  ][, counter := rowid(person, task) - 1][]
#    person   task  score counter
#     <num> <char> <char>   <num>
# 1:      1      A    Low       0
# 2:      1      A    Low       1
# 3:      1      A   High       2
# 4:      1      A Medium       3
# 5:      1      A    Low       4
# 6:      2      B   High       0
# 7:      2      B    Low       1
```

The use of `rowid(.) - 1` is akin to `seq_len(.N) - 1` but more `data.table`-canonical (thanks @zx8754 for the suggestion!).

Comment: Or using rowid: `...][, counter := rowid(person, task) - 1]`